# Custom circular progress bar is not working as expected.

Tags: android, android-progressbar

i am working on custom progress bar which will fades one-by-one so its give us feel like moving circular progress. For this i have declare this xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:id="@+id/customsearcl_ll"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle1_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle2_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle3_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle4_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle5_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle6_imgv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When you see above  xml file you will feel that here **no** any

```
             android:alpha
```

is called.So for changing alpha i declare images as follow

```
    image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle3_imgv);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle5_imgv);
    image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle6_imgv);
    image4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle4_imgv);
    image5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle2_imgv);
    image6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle1_imgv);

    i = 0;
    alpha = (float).8;


   imaArray = new ImageView[] {image1 ,image2,image3,image4,image5, image6};
```

and after that  declare timer as

```
   final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(500 , 500) { 
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        changeAlpha();     
      }

      public void onFinish() {
          Counter1.start(); 

      }
      };
```

Then inside onCreate() called Counter1.start(); So its invoking counter and inside counter called changeAlpha() method.

```
      void changeAlpha(){
        imaArray[i].setAlpha(alpha);
        alpha = (float) (alpha - .2);
        i++;    
        if(i ==5){
            i =0;
            alpha = (float) .8;
        }
       }
```

But problem is that its changing alpha of our drawable but only one time means that its not rotating again and again. Ones its complete 360 degress its stop but expectation is to rotate this images by alpha changing n-times.It will something look like as below

[image]

Comment: Is any body here to solve this problem.?? Please help me.

Comment: Your changeAlpha method IS actually changing the values... It's just changing the values to the same thing every time because your loop never changes the index in your list of where to start the alpha setting from (ie. it's always starting from the same place)